# How can we test a customHook with useEffect with no return values inside by triggering it multiple times?

Tags: react-hooks, ts-jest, react-hooks-testing-library

Hi all I am new to jest and now working on some tests for our customHooks.

My customHook has useEffect inside and does not return value:

```
const useCustomHook = (func: EffectCallback, deps?: DependencyList) => {
  const didMount = useRef(false);

  useEffect(() => {
    if (didMount.current) func();
    else didMount.current = true;
  }, deps);
};
```

What I am trying to do is that the callback function will not be called after the component is mounted, but after the updates in dependencies.

My current test.ts is using jest and @testing-library/react-hooks and is like this:

```
describe('Testing if useCustomHook works as expected', () => {
  test('Check if only fire after dep updates', async () => {
    const callBackMock = jest.fn();
    let dependencyList = [{ dep: 'dep' }];

    const { result,} = renderHook(() =>
      useCustomHook(callBackMock, dependencyList)
    );
    expect(callBackMock).toHaveBeenCalledTimes(0);
    expect(result.current).toBeUndefined();

    act(() => {
      dependencyList[0].dep = 'foo';
    });

    expect(callBackMock).toHaveBeenCalledTimes(1);
  });
});
```

After updating the dependencyList the effect is not triggered again. @testing-library/react-hooks does provide a method called waitForNextUpdate but I got timeout error by using it. As my hook does not return values, result.current is undefined as well.

So, how can I test my hook to be working as expected? Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

I ended up finding the problem is that dependencyList[0].dep = 'foo' does not trigger the useEffect inside my customHook. What I have done to make it work is to 1. instead of create an array then pass to the useEffect, pass [dependency] to it. 2. use rerender after updating the dependency.

```
 test('Check if only fire after dep updates', async () => {
    const callBackMock = jest.fn();
    let dep = 'dep';

    const { result, waitForNextUpdate, waitFor, rerender } = renderHook(() => {
      useDidMountEffect(callBackMock, [dep]);
    });
    expect(callBackMock).toHaveBeenCalledTimes(0);
    expect(result.current).toBeUndefined();

    act(() => {
      dep = 'foo';
    });
    rerender();

    expect(callBackMock).toHaveBeenCalledTimes(1);
  });
```